# SQL Server PIVOT table returns to view (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

To return the data from the sql server to the view giving as a problem for me.
My question is how to return the column titles from the database to a table in a angular app view. The titles are dynamic that means when the user add a new person to the person table in the database then the pivot table is getting a new column with the new person name.

I'm using C# ASP.NET WebAPI 2 & SQL Server 2012 for server side and AngularJS for client side.

The REST Service works with a Stored Procedure in the SQL Server.

For example the normal table is:

```
firstname | lastname | age |
John      |    Doe   |  20 |
Peter     |    Keller|  19 |
Chris     |    Brown |  30 |
Christy   |    Buzzy |  20 |
Phil      |    Brown |  34 |
.....
```

and the PIVOT table:

```
age | Doe | Keller | Brown | Buzzy ....
34  |  0  |    1   |   1   |   0
...
30  |  4  |    0   |   1   |   0
...
20  |  1  |    0   |   0   |   0
```

Table means that for example 4 people with the lastname "Doe" are 30 years old and so on.

Comment: @nicolaskruchten Can you tell me how to use PivotTable.js for Angular? I've downloaded the zip file but there are only coffeescript files.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-striped no-margin">
<thead>
     <tr>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th ng-repeat="l in lastnames">{{l.lastname}}</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="a in age">
         <td>{{a.age}}</td>
         <td ng-repeat="c in count track by $index">{{c.count}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hoping that you are asking for this. Use ng-repeat for your headers.